# Do I need to add IP address to Memgraph instance that runs in docker?

Tags: memgraphdb

Do I need to provide the docker instance with a real IP address instead of a loopback address `127.0.0.1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, it isn't necessary, and you should be able to connect with the default parameters which are `localhost` and `7687`.

But if something is off, you can find the address of the Docker container with:

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' container_name_or_id
```

And you can find the `container_name_or_id` with `docker ps`.
The connection command would look like this:

```
memgraph = Memgraph(host="ip_address", port=7687)
```